# Alamofire 'invalid type in JSON write' error after upgrading

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

The following code was working with Alamofire 3.0:

```
let headers = [
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    ]
let parameters = [
    "access_token": token.tokenString,
    "client_id": bundleID,
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, url, headers: headers, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
    // ...
}
```

I changed the request after updating to Alamofire 4.0/Swift3/XCode 8:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    // ...
}
```

And I get the error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'`

I've been looking for a solution to this problem but can't find anything relevant.

Comment: I think either `token.tokenString` or  `bundleID` is not string as you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely something wrong with your parameters. Make sure that both `token.tokenString` and `bundleID` are `String`s.

Comment: You're right, `token.tokenString` was of type `String?` and explicitly unwrapping it fixes the issue. I can't believe it was so simple! The error message was very unclear to me.